# Php mysql while loop inside foreach loop duplicates

Tags: php

i have a string with data structure like this
$string = "2,3,4,5";
i want to select from my database to get all ids then highlight the exploded string values if equal to the database ids

```
$string = "2,3,4,5";
$exp = explode(",",$string);

foreach($exp as $e) {
    $query = $conn->query("select * from tbl");
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

        $result .= '<option value="" ';
        if($e === $row['id']):
            $result .= ' selected';
        endif;                                      
        $result .= '>';
        $result .= $row['id'];
        $result .= '</option>';

    }
}
```

but i keep on get duplicates like
1234678,12345678,12345678,12345678 Please help ...

Comment: the output seems correct as per the nested loops working. What exactly is your error here?

Comment: the foreach run 4times so is my while loop... The answers provided below all solved my problem .. Thanks to everyone

Comment: Xianlong Wang's solution saves me an extra looping by removing the foreach loop..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to mark id user selected.I will do following two steps:

- get all ids
- check each id is selected or not

```
$query = $con->query("select id from config");
$datas = [];
$result = '';
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {    
    $result .= '<option value="'.$row['id'].'" ';
    if(in_array($row['id'], $exp))
    {
        $result .= ' selected';
    }                                 
    $result .= '>';
    $result .= $row['id'];
    $result .= '</option>';
}
echo $result;
```

result look like:

```
<option value="1"  selected>1</option><option value="2"  selected>2</option>
```

Comment: Your code is perfect and improve its speed with faster performance ... Thanks Alot.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but try below code. In your code, you are running database query in for loop that's a performance hit.

```
    $string = "2,3,4,5";
    $exp = explode(",",$string);

    $query = $conn->query("select * from tbl");
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
     $result .= '<option value="" ';
        foreach($exp as $e){
         if($e === $row['id']){
           $result .= ' selected';
           break;
         }
        }

        $result .= '>';
        $result .= $row['id'];
        $result .= '</option>';

    }
```

Comment: Mixing `if : ... endif` and `{}` notation makes your code very hard to read.

Comment: it was from Okoro's initial code, didn't bother to change it. thanks for pointing it out. changed now.

Comment: So it was... apologies for critiquing you on it.

Comment: I appreciate the solution it works perfectly... God bless you #Pandurang

Answer (score 0):

You should change the positions of foreach and while like :

```
$query = $conn->query("select * from tbl");
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {    
    $result .= '<option value="" ';
    foreach($exp as $e) {
      if($e === $row['id']) {
        $result .= ' selected';
      }
    }                                  
    $result .= '>';
    $result .= $row['id'];
    $result .= '</option>';
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly .. Thank A million time .. God bless you

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is absolutely correct but you are placing loops on wrong place.

As foreach is running every time and also SQL query every time and return first row every time and foreach match that and print same result every time. So simple, you need to place SQL query out of foreach and run it like below

```
$query = $conn->query("select * from tbl");
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {    
  $result .= '<option value="" ';
  foreach($exp as $e) {
    if($e === $row['id']) {
      $result .= ' selected';
    }
  }                                  
 $result .= '>';
 $result .= $row['id'];
 $result .= '</option>';
}
```

You will get required output for sure. Thanks

Comment: I appreciate the solution it works perfectly... Thank you n God bless you #Newton Singh